# spark posexplode function runs very slow

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, orc

I have a spark dataframe stored as orc with about 10000 rows and following schema:

```
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- contig: string (nullable = true)
 |-- start: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- ref: string (nullable = true)
 |-- alt: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gt: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

where arrayField is a list of 200000 integers. I want to transform it to a dataframe with a flat structure:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import posexplode
>>> flat = df.select('contig', 'start', 'ref', 'alt', posexplode(df.gt))
>>> flat.explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*Project [contig#0, start#1, ref#2, alt#3, pos#11, col#12]
+- Generate posexplode(gt#4), true, false, [pos#11, col#12]
   +- *FileScan orc [contig#0,start#1,ref#2,alt#3,gt#4] Batched: false, Format: ORC, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/path/to/data], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<contig:string,start:int,ref:string,alt:string,gt:array<int>>
>>> flat.write.orc('/path/to/output/file')
```

Writing the flattened dataframe to a file takes more than five hours on a machine with 24 CPU cores and over 100GB of memory. Is this just a feature of the posexplode function or is there something else wrong?

Comment: if you explode 200000 integers then 200000 rows for each row are generated. so it is obvious to get slow.

Comment: It's true that we are talking about 2 billion output rows here but is it really that much work for 24 worker threads? The size of the output file is just 1.3GB.

Comment: are you doing some shuffling or transformations that needs shuffling after you explode ? And make sure that all of the 24 executors are working in parallel

Comment: Not that I know of. The only code I'm running is the one written above.

Comment: And I would assume that the executors are working in parallel since they take up about 2000% of CPU time.

Comment: Could you please let us know what your submit parameters are? E.g. worker memory. Also, how many tasks are there created? Do the workers use up all the memory? (the stats of the UI)

Comment: I run pyspark with this command `pyspark --num-executors 24 --driver-memory 72g --executor-memory 3g`. Spark creates 24 tasks, 4 of which finish very fast and the rest take hours to complete. Based on top-command output, the job uses almost 30GB of memory in total.

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure about the 72g for the driver but could you try adjusting the executor memory? More specifically, increase it significantly (assuming you have resources, else, try decreasing the driver memory to compensate) and see if it speeds up the execution.

Comment: It looks like you are reading and writing from and to the local file system. Have you profiled your IO throughput? It looks like that's a very likely bottleneck for this kind of job. Is you machine already doing some other IO-heavy job? If not, what does the operating system tell you about IO usage when the job is running?

Comment: Also, from your comment it looks like there is some form of skew that is making your job parallelism less-than-optimal. Is the original data partitioned or bucketed in some way?

Comment: I personally would suggest you to repartition dataframe in such a way that each 24 executor would get equal partitions before you do posexplode. And then use withColumn function for posexplode and then only use select function. Try it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! So it seems my disk IO is not the bottleneck here. Also, the directory I'm reading the dataframe from contains 20 orc files so it should parallelize pretty nicely (although it can only use 20 threads instead of 24). @RameshMaharjan Do you know a way to use posexplode with withColumn? It seems that they don't work together since posexplode creates two columns (`pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'The number of aliases supplied in the AS clause does not match the number of columns output by the UDTF expected 2 aliases but got <column name> ;`).

Comment: @jrauhamaa, if you need position and value both then it cannot be used with withColumn. You will have to use select as you did.

Comment: pyspark --num-executors 24 --driver-memory 72g --executor-memory 3g. Why 72G driver memory? You are not doing anything in your driver here? Second - you mentioned that 4 of your tasks are finishing very fast and rest of them are taking a lot of time. Can you please post the record counts for each task? Probably you have a skewness in your data and also the way you are allocation your resource is not fine. Once you post back the details, we can look into it further with possible solutions like repartitioning your data before/after you explode and also possible better resource allocation.

Comment: I'm new to spark so that's why the submit args might be insane. 4 of the tasks probably finish fast because there's only 20 source files and therefore meaningful work to do for only 20 workers.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that spark is doing something insane with the rows here. With RDDs I was able to get much better performance (1/3 rows per second per CPU core versus 1/40 rows per second per CPU core of dataframes). This is still not very fast though.

```
df = sql_context.read.orc('/path/to/source/file')
rdd = df.rdd

def expand(row):
    contig, start, ref, alt, gt = row
    def getrow(index, genotype):
        return contig, start, ref, alt, index, genotype
    return [getrow(index, genotype) for index, genotype in enumerate(gt)]

rdd_flat = rdd.flatMap(expand)
schema = ('contig', 'start', 'ref', 'alt', 'index', 'genotype')
sqlc.createDataFrame(rdd_flat, schema=schema).write.orc('/path/to/output/file')
```

What's interesting is that if I redefine expand-function as

```
def expand(row):
    def getrow(index, genotype):
        return Row(
            contig=row.contig,
            start=row.start,
            ref=row.ref,
            alt=row.alt,
            index=index,
            genotype=genotype
        )
    return [getrow(index, genotype) for index, genotype in enumerate(row.gt)]
```

it runs about 13 times slower (a single function call takes about 1.4 seconds).

So clearly, the row objects are extremely inefficient.

There's more, though, to be solved. A single core should be able to run expand-function 9 times per second, but the actual performance is 1 row per 3 seconds.

**EDIT**: Found one 'solution': Use prestodb query instead of spark. This runs at a bit over 1 rows per second per cpu core - over 20 times faster than dataframes and 4 times faster than RDDs:

```
create table flat (
  contig varchar,
  start int,
  ref varchar,
  alt varchar,
  index bigint,
  genotype tinyint
) 
WITH (format = 'ORC');

insert into flat
select contig, start, ref, alt, index, genotype, partition_name
from nested cross join unnest(gt) with ordinality as g (genotype, index)
where partition_name='10-70329347';
```